# Long time to load QGIS project in QGIS 3.22.4

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial

I have several QGIS projects which have layers coming from oracle database. Those layers are heavy so I choose to make them invisible in the projects so that I can load the project much quicker. If i want to open the heavy layer later on then I just click the layer and let it take some time to load the corresponding data to the project.

This has been working fine for version 3.10 and 3.16. But lately I upgradede my QGIS to version 3.22 and now it always take a much longer time to open the projects, and it seems to me that whenever I open the projects then QGIS load all the data from all Oracle layers in the project as well, even though they are not visible in the begining. so now it becomes very long loading time for the projects but very short loading time to make the layers visible.

I wonder if there is anyway to make QGIS back to have same behaviour as 3.16?

Comment: Layer visibility never affected project loading time, as far as I know there were never any defferred loading. The only thing that may have changed is the oracle driver.

Comment: We have tested with several users and we have the same strange behaviour. we have not changed anything from Oracle or Oracle clients.

Comment: You can raise the issue in github if that's a problem and seems to be a bug.